# SQL query to get latest prices, depending on the date

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve a list of products which have been updated, the table contains multiple updates of the products as it records the price changes.

I need to get the latest price changes for all products, but only return the the last update. I have the below code so far, but it only returns the very last update and only 1 product.

```
SELECT dbo.twProducts.title, dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin, dbo.twProducts.sku, 
       dbo.LowestPrices.tweAmzPrice, dbo.LowestPrices.price, dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate
FROM   dbo.aboProducts INNER JOIN
       dbo.LowestPrices ON dbo.aboProducts.asin = dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin 
       INNER JOIN dbo.twProducts ON dbo.aboProducts.sku = dbo.twProducts.sku
WHERE  (dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate =
        (SELECT MAX(priceDate) AS Expr1
         FROM   dbo.LowestPrices AS LowestPrices_1))
```

I hope this makes sense, i am not sure if i have explained it in a way thats easy to understand.

Any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: So the LowestPrices table has a row for every price change?

Comment: yeah, its so we can track the changes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the adjustment to the query you are looking for is to join your subquery rather than just matching on the Date.

```
SELECT dbo.twProducts.title, dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin, dbo.twProducts.sku, 
       dbo.LowestPrices.tweAmzPrice, dbo.LowestPrices.price, dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate
FROM   dbo.aboProducts INNER JOIN
       dbo.LowestPrices ON dbo.aboProducts.asin = dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin 
       INNER JOIN dbo.twProducts ON dbo.aboProducts.sku = dbo.twProducts.sku
WHERE  dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate IN
        (SELECT MAX(LowestPrices_1.priceDate)
         FROM   dbo.LowestPrices AS LowestPrices_1 
         WHERE dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin = LowestPrices_1.productAsin)
```

This will match on the max(priceDate) **for each product**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use a `CTE` with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT dbo.twProducts.title, dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin, dbo.twProducts.sku, 
       dbo.LowestPrices.tweAmzPrice, dbo.LowestPrices.price, dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY productAsin ORDER BY priceDate DESC)
  FROM   dbo.aboProducts INNER JOIN
       dbo.LowestPrices ON dbo.aboProducts.asin = dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin 
       INNER JOIN dbo.twProducts ON dbo.aboProducts.sku = dbo.twProducts.sku
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```