# List of items which were not updated in the last 24 hours

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Morning,
This is similar to a question i asked yesterday [question]: [SQL query to get latest prices, depending on the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198572/sql-query-to-get-latest-prices-depending-on-the-date)

I need to return a list of ASIN's which are have not been updated within 24 hours from the last update date from the lowest price table. I can get a list of ASIN's, however it returns all of them. Could someone pleas help me with the SQL to get this list please?

```
SELECT     asin
FROM       dbo.aboProducts
WHERE     (asin NOT IN
               (SELECT    aboProducts_1.asin
                FROM      dbo.aboProducts AS aboProducts_1 INNER JOIN
                          dbo.LowestPrices ON aboProducts_1.asin = dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin
                WHERE    (dbo.aboProducts.amzLive = 'true') AND 
                         (dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate < DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got your comparison the wrong way round

Try

```
SELECT     asin 
FROM       dbo.aboProducts 
WHERE     (asin NOT IN 
               (SELECT    aboProducts_1.asin 
                FROM      dbo.aboProducts AS aboProducts_1 INNER JOIN 
                          dbo.LowestPrices ON aboProducts_1.asin = dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin 
                WHERE    (dbo.aboProducts.amzLive = 'true') AND  
                         (dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate > DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

@podiluska's answer is correct. Since you are using

```
WHERE     (asin NOT IN
```

you want to get all items which have been updated in the last 24 hours by doing

```
dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate > DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE())
```

and then exclude them by using the NOT IN clause, which will leave you with all items that have not been updated in the last 24 hours.